# VBA Change Body Font and Color in Meeting Invite in Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I need some help here. I am trying to create a meeting invite in Outlook using Excel VBA but I want part of the body text to be a different color than the rest. I've been able to find code on VBA sending emails but nothing on Meeting Invites. Please help :)

I also am looking into adding a photo to the body text as well if there is an extension from this code that I could use.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MeetingInvite()
    ' setting ability to use Outlook from VBA
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMeet As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Set OutApp = Outlook.Application
    Set OutMeet = OutApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
    With OutMeet
        .Subject = "Invitation to " 
        .RequiredAttendees = "john.cena@gmail.com"
        .Start = #1/10/2023 1:00:00 PM#
        .Duration = 60
        .Importance = olImportanceHigh
        .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15
        .Body = "hello" & "all"  'I want only hello in large blue letters
        .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
        .Location = "Zoom"
        .Display
    End With
```

Comment: use htmlbody instead of body and write your custom html  there. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody

Comment: htmlbody does not work for a meeting invite. only actual emails

Answer (score 0):

Use the [RTFBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.rtfbody) property which allows to set a Byte array that represents the body of the Microsoft Outlook item in Rich Text Format.

Also you may consider setting the `PR_HTML` property directly using a low-level code (Extended MAPI or any other wrapper around this API can be used, for example, Redemption) to a byte array (binary representation of the HTML body). The store provider should automatically convert HTML to RTF when the item is saved.

Another option is the Word editor. The [WordEditor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.wordeditor) property returns the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed. So, you may use the Word object model for setting up the message body in Outlook.